# Disabled horizontal scrollbar in Windows listbox

Tags: windows, listbox, scrollbar

Well, I thought I was finished with this kind of question 15 years ago.

What causes the horizontal scrollbar in a Windows listbox to be disabled?  Here's the control definition:

```
    LISTBOX IDC_FOOBAR,6,6,100,60,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | WS_HSCROLL
```

The listbox contains some items that are much longer than can be displayed. The horizontal scrollbar is visible but disabled. The vertical scrollbar is fine.  What gives?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the logical width of the listbox width [LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761344%28VS.85%29.aspx). The horizontal scrollbar is disabled as long as the client width is more than this value.

Comment: That's it, thanks.  I've been programming Windows since 3.0. I can't imagine why I've never run into this before.